# How to get Oanda API Python wrapper oandapy and PyQt work together?

Tags: python, pyqt, streaming

This is a very basic example of a problem I have with **oandapy** and **PyQt**: I can not get them to work together.

The goal is **to activate the GUI window and get the data streaming** (*in this example the data streaming is printed in the terminal window*).

When I activate the oandapy streaming (see `stream.rates(account, instruments="EUR_USD")`) the PyQt GUI (*in this example it is an empty window*) does not appear. In the terminal window you can see the data streaming.

Any help?

Thank you in advance,
gilberto

P.S. To run this example you have to change the `account` and the `access_token` setup, according to your Oanda API account.

```
# --- GUI

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)

# --- OANDA

import oandapy

class Streamer(oandapy.Streamer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Streamer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def on_success(self, data):
        print(data, "\n")

account = "12345"
stream = Streamer(environment="practice", access_token="abc123-def456")

# --- MAIN

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    print('Start')
    #stream.rates(account, instruments="EUR_USD") # if commented, the GUI window appears, otherwise it will not

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## The Solution

Thanks to @ekhumoro suggestion I modified the code as the following (just an example, with no need of Oanda credentials).

```
# --- GUI

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)

# --- TEST LOOP

import time

def loop(): # this is a test function
    while 1:
        print('.', sep=' ', end='', flush=True) # print "." in line
        time.sleep(1) # pause 1 sec

# --- THREADING

from threading import Thread

# --- MAIN

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    print('\n\n BEFORE \n\n')

    # loop() # this blocks
    Thread(target=loop).start() # this doesn't block, check the terminal

    print('\n\n AFTER \n\n')

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### The code for Oanda

```
# --- GUI

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)

# --- OANDA

import oandapy

class Streamer(oandapy.Streamer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Streamer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def on_success(self, data):
        print(data, "\n")


def DataStream():
    account = "..."
    stream = Streamer(environment="practice", access_token="...")
    stream.rates(account, instruments="EUR_USD")

# --- THREADING

from threading import Thread

# --- MAIN

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    print('Start')
    Thread(target=DataStream).start() # this doesn't block

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well, obviously the streamer runs a blocking loop. If it hasn't got an asychronous API, you'll have to run it in a separate thread and use signals to communicate with the gui. There are lots of examples on SO and elsewhere that show how to do that.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you. I'm quite new to Python so now I don't know how to do it, but I will search.